# Найти длину наименьшей повторяющейся последовательности в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Например, дана строка abcabcabc (3 раза повторяется "abc", длина - 3 символа)
или 1111 (4 раза повторяется "1", длина 1)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать для строк очень большой длины.
(входная строка полностью состоит из одинаковой повторяющейся последовательности)

Comment: В строке могут быть еще какие-то символы до и после нескольких повторений последовательности?

Comment: Нет, не могут ("abcabcabc ... abc")

Comment: Тогда к написанному @AnT добавьте делимость длины строки на период :)

Answer (score 1):

В такой постановке алгоритм выглядит тривиальным. Сначала предполагаем, что повторяющаяся последовательность - это первый символ строки. Если второй символ соответствует этой гипотезе, переходим к чтению третьего и т.д. Если вдруг обнаруживается символ, который не соответствует текущей гипотезе о повторяющейся последовательности, то все начало строки вплоть до этого символа (и включая его) становится новой версией повторяющейся последовательности. Продолжая читать символы строки мы проверяем теперь уже новую гипотезу и т.д. до конца строки.

В случае "abcabcabc" мы начинаем с предположения "a". Следующий же символ заставляет нас сменить наше предположение на "ab". Следующий символ заставит нас перейти к гипотезе "abc". А эта гипотеза уже продержится до конца строки. Ответ: "abc".

Comment: Пробовал делать циклом (разбивая исходную строку на равные части и затем сравнивая образовавшиеся подстроки). Но для больших входных строк работает медленно и не на 100% правильно)

Comment: http://sbornik-obrazov-dlya-bochs-i-qemu.ru/pub/sample.txt P.S. Видимо, этот код не всегда работает правильно (судя по тестам)

Comment: А все перебирать и не надо. Достаточно только делители длины строки.